# TravelItineraryReadService VB error

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wsdl, sabre

When trying to use the TravelItineraryReadService 3.8.0 service via VB i get the following error just by doing

```
Private service As TravelItineraryReadService     
service = New TravelItineraryReadService
```

the error output:

```
at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
   at PricingContingency.TravelItineraryRQ1.TravelItineraryReadService..ctor()
```

i am using visual studio 2015,
added the WSDL as [image: webservice wsdl added]

it doesn't matter if i add the header info or not. it always fails.

Comment: Shouldn't `TravelItineraryReadService service` be `Dim service as TravelItineraryReadService` ?

Comment: correcting the code

Comment: @ProGrammer found an issue with the generationg by the wsdl.
when instancing the service i get the following error:
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'TravelItineraryTest.TravelItineraryReadRQ1.TravelItineraryReadRSTravelItineraryItineraryInfoItineraryPricingPriceQuoteMiscInformationTicketingFeesFeeInformationAssociatedDataAssociatedDataItem[]' to 'TravelItineraryTest.TravelItineraryReadRQ1.TravelItineraryReadRSTravelItineraryItineraryInfoItineraryPricingPriceQuoteMiscInformationTicketingFeesFeeInformationAssociatedDataAssociatedDataItem'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to response object issue in generated web service proxy class.
Changed the following and works well for me.

1.
 Private associatedDataField()() As TravelItineraryReadRSTravelItineraryItineraryInfoItineraryPricingPriceQuoteMiscInformationTicketingFeesFeeInformationAssociatedDataAssociatedDataItem

----change as below-- Private associatedDataField() As

TravelItineraryReadRSTravelItineraryItineraryInfoItineraryPricingPriceQuoteMiscInformationTicketingFeesFeeInformationAssociatedDataAssociatedDataItem

2. Public Property AssociatedData() As TravelItineraryReadRSTravelItineraryItineraryInfoItineraryPricingPriceQuoteMiscInformationTicketingFeesFeeInformationAssociatedDataAssociatedDataItem()()

----change as below--

Public Property AssociatedData() As TravelItineraryReadRSTravelItineraryItineraryInfoItineraryPricingPriceQuoteMiscInformationTicketingFeesFeeInformationAssociatedDataAssociatedDataItem()

Comment: Thanks! Found out that in the comments of another post. Marking as the answer.